# Why two names for the headset which we use?

Tags: usage

The headset which is used for listening why it is called EARPHONE  and AIRPHONE both?

Comment: Airphone is the one fitted in an aircraft for in-flight use.

Comment: The only Airphones I've heard of is the [app](https://www.wired.com/2009/02/airphones-turns/)

Answer (score 3):

Headset is a combination of headphones and a microphone.

Earphones are the ones you place inside your ear. These are also sometimes called Earbuds (as mentioned by Andrew in the comments).

Airphones aren't an actual thing I believe. But it could also be one fitted in an aircraft for in-flight use. As mentioned by Ms. Tamil in the comments, but I hold no guarantee this is correct.

Headphones are the ones you place on top of your head with usually over-ear stereos.

Comment: *Earphones* are also called *earbuds*, or sometimes just *buds*.  *Airphones* sounds like a brand name for some wireless version of earphones.

Comment: I have heard of earbuds, but never just buds, I'll add that to the answer for clearer definition. @Andrew

Comment: Well, *buds* would only make sense in context, e.g. *"Here let me share my **buds** with you so we can both listen"*  Otherwise the meaning would be ambiguous, as there are are about eight definitions for "buds".

Comment: Thanks for the help. Well can I conclude that the equipment which is used to listen to the music is EARPHONES  and not AIRPHONES?

Comment: Apologies for the late answer, the equipment which you place **inside** your ear are called Earphones yes, the ones you place **over** are headphones. Airphones are not a tool for listening to music, if even a real tool at all. @AltafJahangir

Comment: Veraen I can't thank you enough for the reflection. In absolute agreement with your response. Dictionaries too give the same opinion but I was disturbed by the excessive misuse of the so called phrase AIRPHONE by the people around .thanks

Comment: No worries, glad you got it all sorted out! @AltafJahangir